# how do I make a custom comperater function for c++ PBDS?

Tags: c++

Here is my implementation. But it gives me type error like

```
[ error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template<class Key, class Mapped, class Cmp_Fn, class Tag, template<class Node_CItr, class Node_Itr, class Cmp_Fn_, class _Alloc_> class Node_Update, class _Alloc> class __gnu_pbds::tree'
   13 | using oset = tree<type, null_type, comp_fx<type>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
      |                                                                                                 ^
e.cpp:13:97: note:   expected a type, got 'comp_fx<type>' ]
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

template <class T>
bool comp_fx( T a, T b ){
 return a < b;
}

template <class type>
using oset = tree<type, null_type, comp_fx<type>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of an error does it produce?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Finishing the last sentence in your description and stating the exact error could help

Comment: I have added the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer,
instead of using comp_fx as function, I can use class and overload the ( ) operator such as

```
template <class T>
struct comp_fx
{
    bool operator()(const T &a, const T &b)
    {

        return a < b;
    }
};
```

c++ PBDS is one the best data structure I have ever used.
So, I posted my own answer may be it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `tree` expects a type, but comp_fx is a value of type `bool(*)(...)`.

You could wrap your comparison function in a class and overload the function call operator and then pass this class to `tree`